# Data with useState is not updated and is replicated

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

When making a loop to parse my API data, I need to capture the values ​​of the data obtained and dynamically load the corresponding components according to their characteristics. The problem that after using **useState()** the **TextField** and the **Checkbox** always take a single value and do not update the changes. That is, if I click on one element, that data is taken and propagated to the others.

The code is:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Box, Checkbox, TextField } from '@mui/material';

export interface IFormsProps {
  columns: any;
  data: any;
  typeElement: any;
}

export default function FormEdit(props: any) {
  const { columns, data, typeElement } = props;

  const keys = Object.keys(data);
  let counter = 0;
  const box: any = [];

  if (keys.length > 0) {
    for (let pos = 0; pos < columns.length; pos++) {
      const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(data[keys[pos]]);
      const [content, setData] = React.useState(data[keys[pos]]);

      const changeValue = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setData(e.target.value);
      };

      const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setChecked(!e.target.checked);
      };

      switch (typeElement[keys[counter++]].type) {
        case 'textBox':
          box.push(
            <TextField
              color="warning"
              InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
              id="outlined"
              label={columns[pos].headerName}
              value={content} // I need change and update this
              onChange={changeValue}
            />,
          );
          break;
        case 'checkBox':
          box.push(
            <div>
              <Checkbox
                color="success"
                checked={checked} // I need change and update this
                onChange={handleChange}
                inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'controlled' }}
              />
              active
            </div>,
          );
          break;
        case 'numberBox':
          box.push(
            <TextField
              color="warning"
              id="outlined-number"
              label={columns[pos].headerName}
              type="number"
              onChange={changeValue}
              value={content}    // I need change and update this
              InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true,
              }}
            />,
          );
          break;
        case 'idBox':
          box.push(
            <TextField
              InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
              id="outlined"
              disabled
              label={columns[pos].headerName}
              value={data[keys[pos]]} 
            />,
          );
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <Box
      component="form"
      sx={{
        '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 1, width: '29ch' },
      }}
      noValidate
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      {box}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Example: If the values ​​taken are { "ID": 1, "name": "x", "category": "x1", "default": true }, which are captured by content and checked, when interacting with another element (which would have { "ID": 34, "name": "z", "category": "z34", "default": false }, this one doesn't have those values. Instead it would have the first ones. That's all the cases.

Comment: For starters you are [breaking the rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). Namely "Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions."

Comment: it's okay. I need to fix this. What do you suggest for this situation?

Comment: No it's not OK :) If you break the rules, don't be surprised it's not working ;) You must try to have just one state, so build an object with your loop, an set it as one single state !

Answer (score 1):

You want to try to have all the info you need in the state, then render once based on that. [Hooks are not allowed in loops](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), so you could update a single state instead of trying to create multiple in the loop. The problem of having handlers for each input can be solved by having a higher order function that returns a new handler specific to the input it's for. The following code is not optimized, but should work.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Box, Checkbox, TextField } from '@mui/material';

export interface IFormsProps {
  columns: any;
  data: any;
  typeElement: any;
}

export default function FormEdit(props: any) {
  const { columns, data, typeElement } = props;

  const keys = Object.keys(data);

  // stores the value for each input element
  const [inputs, setInputs] = React.useState((): any => {
    const inputs: any = [];
    
    if (keys.length === 0) {
      return inputs;
    }

    for (let pos = 0; pos < columns.length; pos++) {
      inputs.push(data[keys[pos]]);
    }

    return inputs;
  });

  // returns a handler for a particular input element and can handle based on element type
  const handleChange = (index: number) => (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setInputs(prev => {
      const newInputs = [...prev];
      const inputType = typeElement[keys[index]].type;

      if (inputType === 'checkbox') {
        newInputs[index] = !e.target.checked;
      } else {
        newInputs[index] = e.target.value;
      }

      return newInputs;
    });
  }

  return (
    <Box
      component="form"
      sx={{
        '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 1, width: '29ch' },
      }}
      noValidate
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      {
        keys.length > 0 ? inputs.map((value, index) => {
          switch (typeElement[keys[index]].type) {
            case 'textBox':
              return (
                <TextField
                  color='warning'
                  InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                  id='outlined'
                  label={columns[index].headerName}
                  value={value} // I need change and update this
                  onChange={handleChange(index)}
                />
              );
            case 'checkBox':
              return (
                <div>
                  <Checkbox
                    color='success'
                    checked={value} // I need change and update this
                    onChange={handleChange(index)}
                    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'controlled' }}
                  />
                  active
                </div>
              );
            case 'numberBox':
              return (
                <TextField
                  color='warning'
                  id='outlined-number'
                  label={columns[index].headerName}
                  type='number'
                  onChange={handleChange(index)}
                  value={value} // I need change and update this
                  InputLabelProps={{
                    shrink: true,
                  }}
                />
              );
            case 'idBox':
              return (
                <TextField
                  InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                  id='outlined'
                  disabled
                  label={columns[index].headerName}
                  value={value}
                />
              );
            default:
              return <></>;
          }
        }) : <></>
      }
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Interesting and thank you Ace. I was unaware of these features of react. it's about learning this as you go. The only problem i'm having with this code is: "typeElement[keys[index]] is undefined" "Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 columnHeaderDragStart listeners added." So the service goes down and the screen remains blank

Comment: @MartínLC I now see you had a check for if `keys` is empty. I have incorporated that into my answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thx Ace! I understand that it is a matter of implementing EventEmitter on the one hand. And it seems strange to me that typeElement[keys[index]].type returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
    box.push(
        <div>
          <Checkbox
            color="success"
            checked={() => setChecked(checked)}
            onChange={handleChange}
            inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'controlled' }}
          />
          active
        </div>,
      );
```

Comment: thanks but this answer doesn't fix the issue of dynamically loading the correct content in each textfield